# Populating model from different views (session state?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state

I have two views for two actions gathering information from the user to populate different properties of the same model. For example(something simple) :
Model:

```
String Name {get; set;} 
String Status {get; set;}
```

Name should be received received from view UserDetails.cshtml and Status from UserStatus.cshtml.
I was told this could be done with Session State. Could anyone give me an example how this could/should be done ? Thanks.

Comment: Are `UserStatus.cshtml` and `UserDetails.cshtml` partial views of same page?

Comment: @Jayantha, No these are from different pages.

Answer (score 0):

the Session object is really just a dictionary. So assuming you have action methods like these

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserDetails(string Name) {
    var model = (Model)Session["ModelKey"];
    model.Name = Name;
    Session["ModelKey"]   = model;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserStatus(string Status) {
    var model = (Model)Session["ModelKey"];
    model.Status= Status;
    Session["ModelKey"]   = model;
}
```